# Ajuda para a tela de "saveAs" do Java

Tags: java

tudo bem? Alguém sabe me dizer como faço para, quando eu clicar no botão salvar, abra a tela de "saveAs" do próprio Windows? No código, estou salvando em um lugar fixo, mas quero abrir a tela e poder escolher onde salvar. (obs: já fiz com o JFileChooser, mas não curti muito a interface da tela)

```
private void salvarTxt(){
   String caminho = "";
   if((jTextField1.getText().isEmpty()) || (jTextField2.getText().isEmpty())){
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Preencha todos os campos!");

   }else{
        String nome = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite um nome para salvar o arquivo");
        try {
            File fl = new File("C:/Users/Rogério/Documents/"+ nome +".txt");
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fl);
            pw.println(jTextField2.getText());
            pw.println(jTextField1.getText());
            pw.close();

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Dados salvos com sucesso!");
            jTextField1.setText(null);
            jTextField2.setText(null);

       }catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
   }

}

}
```

Comment: Com interface grafica e swing, somente com JFileChooser para conseguir isso.

Comment: Ou se você pode criar uma implementação disso do zero, o que seria uma bobagem já que o JFileChooser atende bem pra isso.